# Sample code for RevenueCat in-app functions in Xamarin Forms or .NET Maui?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, sample, revenuecat

I'm publishing some sample code here as I was unable to find any when developing a Xamarin Forms app with RevenueCat.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code from my Xamarin Forms app for iOS and Android is at https://github.com/BillFulton/RevenueCatXamarin.

It presumably will also run in Maui with little if any change.

Comment: Preview MAUI bindings: https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/use-with-xamarin-maui-1512?postid=9610#post9610